# LINQ with SUM for TimeSpan, GROUP and JOIN for EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

In my EF model:
[image]

I make this view:

[image]

with following LINQ query (with your help):

```
var query = ctx.data.ToList().OrderBy(d => d.Time).
     GroupBy(d => d.Members.StepId).
     SelectMany(g => g.Select((d, place) => new { Time = d.Time, Members = d.Members, PlaceInStep = place + 1 })).
     GroupBy(d => d.Members.TeamId).
     Select(g => new 
     {
         TeamId = g.Key, 
         Name = g.Select(d => d.Members.Teams.TeamName).First(),  
         Members = g.Select(d => new {Time = d.Time, PlaceInStep = d.PlaceInStep, MemberName = d.Members.MemberName}),                    
         TotalTime = g.Aggregate(new TimeSpan(), (sum, nextData) => sum.Add(nextData.Time))
     });
```

But I've two issues:

**1. If 2 members in same Step (for ex. before 35 year old) have same time up to milliseconds they must have same place**

**2. In Members subcollection in result I want to arrange members by StepId and show StepName.**

How to modify this query? Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

I want to take some this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Query to calculate correct member place:

```
select *, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by StepId order by Time)
from Members m
join Data d on m.MemberId =d.MemberId
```

linq equivalent adopted to existing linq query:

```
var query = context.Data.ToList()
    .OrderBy(d=>d.Time)
    .GroupBy(d => d.Members.StepId)
    .SelectMany(g => 
        g.OrderBy(d => d.Time)
        .GroupBy(d => d.Time)
        .SelectMany((x, place) => 
            x.Select(d => new { Time = d.Time, Members = d.Members, PlaceInStep = place + 1 })))
    .GroupBy(d => d.Members.TeamId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        TeamId = g.Key,
        Name = g.Select(d => d.Members.Teams.TeamName).First(),
        Members = g.Select(d => 
            new 
            { 
                Time = d.Time, 
                PlaceInStep = d.PlaceInStep, 
                MemberName = d.Members.MemberName, 
                StepName = d.Members.Steps.StepName, 
                StepId = d.Members.Steps.StepId 
            }).OrderBy(x=>x.StepId),
        TotalTime = g.Aggregate(new TimeSpan(), (sum, nextData) => sum.Add(nextData.Time))
    });
```